# Large file upload issue with PHP and FTP

Tags: php, ftp

i am having an issue with a component of a website i am designing. i am having trouble uploading files through the page... PHP is capped at 32mb. the file system i am working on, i expect files in the neighbourhood of 500mb. Most around 250-300... but want that buffer. i have heard of direct ftp uploads through. I do believe this is the direction i need to go in:

```
   <?php
// connect and login to FTP server
$ftp_server = "ftp.example.com";
$ftp_conn = ftp_connect($ftp_server) or die("Could not connect to $ftp_server");
$login = ftp_login($ftp_conn, $ftp_username, $ftp_userpass);

$file = "localfile.txt";

// upload file
if (ftp_put($ftp_conn, "serverfile.txt", $file, FTP_ASCII))
  {
  echo "Successfully uploaded $file.";
  }
else
  {
  echo "Error uploading $file.";
  }

// close connection
ftp_close($ftp_conn);
?>
```

this would be my html and php.

```
<?php
include_once(db_conx.php);
?><?php
error_reporting(E_ALL);
if(isset($_POST['submit'])){


    $name = $_FILES['file']['name'];
    $temp = $_FILES['file']['tmp_name'];

    move_uploaded_file($temp,"vids/".$file);
    $url = "http://x-webb.com/vids/.$file";

}
?>

<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html>
<head>
<title>video uploader</title>
<meta name="" content="">
</head>
<body>
    <h1>Video Uploader</h1>
<form  method="POST" enctype="multipart/form-data">

    Video: <br>
    <input type="file" name="name"><br />

    <label for="title">Title:</label><br>
    <input type="text" name="title" id="title" placeholder="required" ><br>

    <label for="description">Description:</label><br>
    <textarea name="description" id="description" placeholder="required" ></textarea><br>

    <label for="tags">Tags:</label><br>
    <textarea name="tags" id="tags" placeholder="required" ></textarea><br>
<input type="submit" value="upload">
</form>
</body>
</html>
```

i just cant seem to put the 2 together. I have the **ftp_conx.php** file for the ftp server..checked out ok... no errors. 
i have been programing for a hobby for about 18 months with html and CSS... about 2 months with ajax and php. my built pages are 
autodude666.com/network
x-webb.com
current project, where i wish to place this code, is :
http://x-webb.com

ANY help would be GREATLY appreciated. TY in advance.

Answer (score 0):

You can increase the maximum upload size in PHP. Adjust in php.ini:

```
upload_max_filesize = 500M
post_max_size = 500M
```

Additionally, you should consider the amount of time it takes a user to upload a 500MB file and set the maximum time limit accordingly.

I see that you're using Apache from the server signature header of the site you provided, but for anyone else who might be running nginx + php-fpm, you also have to increase the value of [`client_max_body_size`](http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_core_module.html#client_max_body_size) in the http block of your nginx config or you'll see 413 errors.